# My subplots are decreasing in height. Is there a way to keep them constant

Tags: python, matplotlib

My subplots are decreasing in height. Is there a way to keep them constant. The height of Each row should be constant.

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf

for index,store in enumerate(StoreData):
   print('\033[1m PACF AND ACF for Store:', store, '\033[0m')
   lag_acf = acf(StoreData[store]['Sales'], nlags=20) # MA 
   lag_pacf = pacf(StoreData[store]['Sales'], nlags=20, method='ols')  # AR 

   #Plot PACF
   plt.subplot(str(index+1),2,1)
   plt.plot(lag_pacf)
   plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
   plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
   plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
   plt.title('Partial Autocorrelation Function')

  #Plot ACF:
  plt.subplot(str(index+1),2,2)
  plt.plot(lag_acf)
  plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
  plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
  plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
  plt.title('Autocorrelation Function')            

  # plt.tight_layout()   
  plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call signature for plt.subplot is `subplot(nrows, ncols, index, **kwargs)` ([matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html))

You should fix your code accordingly by setting `nrows` to the number of stores and computing the right index:

```
n_stores = len(StoreData)

for index,store in enumerate(StoreData):
   # ...
   plt.subplot(n_stores, 2, 2*index+1) # +1 for PACF, +2 for ACF

   # ...
```

Comment: You rock!
above solution with plt.subplots(figsize=(15,50)) in loop worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your figure is divided each time the command `plt.subplot` is executed. Have you tried first creating the layout and then select the right axis to plot using `plt.subplots` (additional S)?

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(StoreData), 2)

for index,store in enumerate(StoreData):
   print('\033[1m PACF AND ACF for Store:', store, '\033[0m')
   lag_acf = acf(StoreData[store]['Sales'], nlags=20) # MA 
   lag_pacf = pacf(StoreData[store]['Sales'], nlags=20, method='ols')  # AR 

   #Plot PACF
   plt.sca(axs[index][0])
   plt.plot(lag_pacf)
   plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
   plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
   plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
   plt.title('Partial Autocorrelation Function')

  #Plot ACF:
  plt.sca(axs[index][1])
  plt.plot(lag_acf)
  plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
  plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
  plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(StoreData[store]['Sales'])), linestyle='--', color='gray')
  plt.title('Autocorrelation Function')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! this kind of worked. But not my all print statement is above the subplots. Is there a way to print one statement and then a subplot with 2coloumn and so on?  
https://ibb.co/mqVvBwm